# Sobel edge detection using opencv

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, sobel

I am using the built-in Sobel edge operation in openCV for some image processing purpose but the results are not as expected for the function.

```
sobel=cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=3)
cv2.imshow('Sobel Image',sobel)
```

I am attaching a sample image of the input image and the resultant output which I have got.
Please help me regarding this.
On the left is the input image and on the right is the resultant image.

[image]

Comment: I don’t know much about `cv.imshow`, but a lot of this type of image display assumes floating-point data is in the [0,1] range. In your case it is a lot larger (input image in range [0,255]), and consequently the display doesn’t show the image properly. You want to scale the image intensities to a proper range before display.

Comment: `imshow()` accepts integers (8uint, 16uint or 32int), and floating-point numbers (32 and 64-bit). Besides 8uint, the other ones are mapped to [0-255] range before displayng. See more on opencv docs: https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563

Comment: please provide your input image so that other users could test it

Answer (score 9):

The Sobel operator gives you the gradient in x or y direction. For Sobel-based edge detection you compare the magnitude of the gradient to a threshold to decide which pixels are edges. The code below shows how to compute the gradient (magnitude) and display it normalized.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def sobel_edge_detector(img):
    grad_x = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0)
    grad_y = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1)
    grad = np.sqrt(grad_x**2 + grad_y**2)
    grad_norm = (grad * 255 / grad.max()).astype(np.uint8)
    cv2.imshow('Edges', grad_norm)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Note: OpenCV's [tutorial page on Sobel Derivatives](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html) uses the following calculations, but they're both incorrect.

```
// converting back to CV_8U
convertScaleAbs(grad_x, abs_grad_x);
convertScaleAbs(grad_y, abs_grad_y);
...
addWeighted(abs_grad_x, 0.5, abs_grad_y, 0.5, 0, grad);
```

Comment: This is a very good explanation and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Can you please explain why is `convertScaleAbs` incorrect

Comment: @Ankit The [tutorial page](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html) states "sometimes the following simpler equation is used" and gives the sum of absolute gradient components as an approximation to the gradient magnitude calculation. Even then, the code uses `convertScaleAbs` which can cause clipping of values due to converting to 8-bit, then takes the average gradient component, not the sum. The resulting value can be visualised usefully to give an indication of gradient magnitude but it is not strictly a gradient magnitude or even an approximation of one.

Answer (score 8):

You have to make two sobel operations and blend them. Also, be sure you are working on a gray-scaled image, otherwise I think it will process each channel separately..

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

grad_x = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=3)
grad_y = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=3)

abs_grad_x = cv2.convertScaleAbs(grad_x)
abs_grad_y = cv2.convertScaleAbs(grad_y)

grad = cv2.addWeighted(abs_grad_x, 0.5, abs_grad_y, 0.5, 0)

cv2.imshow('grad X',grad_x)
cv2.imshow('grad Y',grad_y)
cv2.imshow('Sobel Image',grad)
cv2.waitKey()
```

The results for `x`, `y` and blended image are:

[image]

If you need to reduce noise, you may apply a Gaussian Blur. Refer to: https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html

Comment: What's the purpose of `cv2.convertScaleAbs`?

Comment: @Haidepzai It takes the output from Sobel operation and converts it back to an 8-bit image (CV_8U type).